# Is it possible to transfer the content of a Winform to a UserControl?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a Winform with 2 tabs that contains several actions (account login, DataGridView ect..), and I would like to customize these 2 tabs.
Is it possible to transfer the content of the 2 tabs to 2 UserControls?

Thanks

Comment: Without the basic structure of this Winform is hard to answer for sure. But in general you can do that, just load the UserControls inside of the main Winform.